# windows - tensorflow - Fail to find the dnn implementation and GPU not detected on older tensorflow version

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm running with the following versions:

```
windows 10
cuda 11.6
cudnn 8.4
python 3.8.10
```

Those versions works when I'm running `torch` models (I can run `torch` models on GPU !).

I'm trying to install and run `tensorflow` models.

When I installed `tensorflow 2.4.0` or `2.4.1` the GPU is not detected via:

```
import tensorflow
physical_devices = tensorflow.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

No GPU is detected (`physical_devices` is empty)

When I upgraded the tensorflow version to 2.8, the GPU is detected (`physical_devices` is not empty)

I'm run the following command before building and fitting my `tensorflow` (`tensorflow.keras`) model:

```
import tensorflow
physical_devices = tensorflow.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tensorflow.config.experimental.set_memoty_growth(physical-devices[0], enable=True)
```

But I'm getting error:

```
Failed to find the dnn implementation
```

- I can't change the `CUDA & CUDNN` versions because they works for my `torch` models (which used GPU and it works fine there).

What do I need to do in order to work with `tensorflow` with GPU in my machine ?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration setup was not matching with the installed `Tensorflow version 2.4`,`cuDNN 8.4` and `CUDA 11.6` in your system. This is the reason for the above error. `Tensorflow 2.4` is supported with `cuDNN 8.0` and `CUDA 10.0` as per this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).

Likewise, you need to install `cuDNN 8.1` and `CUDA 11.2` to run `TensorFlow 2.8` with GPU support in your system. So Please try again by installing the exact configuration setup mentioned below.[image]